# Does a user need to be invited to AppVeyor when using GitHub integration?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, appveyor

I read the [documentation](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/team-setup/#github-integration) about the GitHub integration in AppVeyor and one thing is still not clear to me:

1. When I want to use GitHub teams, do I still need to invite people to be collaborators in AppVeyor?

[image: Users & Collaborators]

2. If so, how does it work with permissions? If both GitHub teams and users/collaborators are assigned to roles, what does take precedence? Eg. user is directly assigned to an "Administrators" role and also a member of a GitHub team with a lower set of permissions. Are the two sets of permissions combined somehow?
3. In other words, is it possible to manage access to AppVeyor only through GitHub teams? (Without having to invite users to AppVeyor.) If not, what's the point of GitHub teams integration...?

I configured several GitHub teams from our organization (Kentico) with certain roles in AppVeyor. However, the users belonging to the GitHub teams didn't see the Kentico account in AppVeyor when they signed in with their GitHub account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to:

1. Revoke access and authorize again at https://ci.appveyor.com/account/kentico/authorizations - **DIDN'T WORK**
2. Remove and recreate the GitHub team at https://ci.appveyor.com/account/kentico/github-teams - **DIDN'T WORK**
3. Verify that both `AppVeyor` and `AppVeyor CI` are authorized OAuth apps at https://github.com/settings/applications - **DIDN'T WORK**
4. Reinstalled AppVeyor from GitHub marketplace: https://github.com/marketplace/appveyor - **WORKED**

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not have to invite GitHub team members (though you can). They should see your account in top left drop down when logged with GitHub button.
2. If you still invite them, GitHub team role takes over role you assigned in invitation.
3. Yes, you should be able just use GitHub teams. When GitHub team member login into AppVeyor with GitHub button, hidden Collaborator automatically created.

Let us troubleshoot your specific users over support ticket you created on our forum.